# Cakephp select database in base of login

Tags: php, mysql, database, cakephp

I would like to know if there is a way to do a multiple database system

For example I have many clients registered to my system and I want when the y login to select its databasse because I want to divide every client with an own database. Is this correct? Because I want to separate information of each client.
Well, I think that i have to make multipl configuration into the database file of cakephp but I don't know hot to do this:
When the client make the lgin (use default database), when they login I want to take a variable inside a table that contain the name of its database and after make it the active database.

is this possible?
I can't declare foreach client the database configuration.

Can anyone help me in this?

Thanks

This is my actual default database in database.php

```
public $default = array (
        'datasource' => 'Database/Mysql',
        'persistent' => false,
        'host' => 'localhost',
        'login' => 'login',
        'password' => 'password_',
        'database' => 'default_db',
        'prefix' => ''
    );
```

I would like to separate database because I want to create some pages where every client can edit filed of some tables because for example: if they want to add to table project field `notes`, they can, anotoher client don't want this filed but many and many others. I would like to create a system to get the possibility to edit some table.
For that there are two solution:
- separate database at login in base of login
- use a unique database ad every time a user registered I create automatically its table for example there isn't table `project` but `project_{user_id}` for example, every user can have its table.

Which method is better?

Thanks

Comment: Why exactly would you want to do that in the first place? Don't they share the same table schemas? Anyways, have a look at [`ConnectionManager::create()`](http://api.cakephp.org/2.4/class-ConnectionManager.html#_create) and [`Model::setDataSource()`](http://api.cakephp.org/2.4/class-Model.html#_setDataSource).

Comment: edi my question with more details @ndm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to divide every client with an own database. Is this correct?
>   I think it's not a good idea to realize this task using CakePHP, but it is possible, take a look to [CakePHP DataSources](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/datasources.html). In simple way your solution should be like this:

1. Setup main database, containing some application-specified data.
2. Authorize user, using MySQL built-in technologies.
3. Use another DataSource with authorized user access-data.

You must take care of granting privileges.

> Which method is better?

It depends of user amount. If it is two or three, there is no difference between your methods. But if it is 100 or 1000 it will be hard to manage your tables. Remember Ockhman's words: entities must not be multiplied beyond necessity. Use MySQL-way, databases must store tables, users can access databases. Don't break this rule.

Also take a look at PHPMyAdmin, maybe it will be better to change it for your needs, it is licensed under GNU GPL2 license.